# jssor - Go to next slide when clicking a "next" button or selecting a radio button

Tags: button, radio-button, jssor, responsive-slides

I am using the jssor Tab Slider to create an animated form. I want to add the option to move to the next slide within the content (not just by clicking the tabs at the top...)

2 ways I want to move to the next slide:

1. Select a radio button
2. Click continue button

I've tried adding data-u="arrowright" to my continue button, and it completely erased my tab navigation. I'm still not sure how to even start with the radio buttons.

Answer (score 2):

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...;

$('img.next').click(function () {
    jssor_slider1.$Next();
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This didn't work. I have this: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('img.next').click(function () {
  jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(1);
        });
});
</script>

Comment: It worked. Please make sure you placed the code at right place. See  updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks so much. For anyone wanting the radio button code, this worked for me.
$('input:radio').change(function(e){
 var $this = $(this);
 jssor_slider2.$Next();
 $(this).blur();
 e.preventDefault();
});

Answer (score -1):

jssor_slider1.$GoTo( myImageNum )